# Find the next hop MAC address for ethernet header when sending custom skbuff from Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel, ethernet

I am constructing my own TCP packets in Linux kernel by populating `skbuff` data structure and sending it out via `dev_queue_xmit`. The communication is happening over WAN.

However, I am completely stack at finding the correct destination MAC address and assembling Ethernet header in the kernel. 
To test my current implementation I hardcoded the next hop MAC and I was able to establish the communication.

How can I correctly assemble Ethernet header in the kernel by knowing the destination IP? I would like to avoid using raw kernel sockets to perform sending operation if possible.

I would appreciate if you could point out some examples.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is my initial code to create skbuff

```
static struct sk_buff* construct_tcp_skb(struct net_device *dev, char * usr_data, uint16_t usr_data_len) {

    unsigned char srcmac[] = {0x03, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x4f, 0xa4, 0x02};
    unsigned char dstmac[] = {0x03, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x30, 0xba, 0x12};

    struct ethhdr *ethh;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr * tcph;
    struct sk_buff *skb;

    unsigned char * p_usr_data;
    int err = 0;
    int tcplen = 0;    

    uint16_t header_len = 300;
    skb = alloc_skb(1000, GFP_KERNEL);
    skb_reserve(skb, header_len);

    tcph = (struct tcphdr*) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    iph = (struct iphdr*) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr));
    ethh = (struct ethhdr*) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    memcpy(ethh->h_source, srcmac, 6);
    memcpy(ethh->h_dest, dstmac, 6);
    ethh->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);    

    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->ttl = 32;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;    
    iph->saddr = my_inet_addr("192.168.0.2");
    iph->daddr = my_inet_addr("192.168.0.1");

    iph->check = ip_fast_csum((u8 *)iph, iph->ihl);
    iph->check = 0;
    iph->id = 12345;
    iph->frag_off = 0;
    iph->tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + usr_data_len );
    ip_send_check(iph);

    tcph->source = htons(12457); 
    tcph->dest = htons(5200);   
    tcph->seq = htonl(100000);
    tcph->ack_seq = htonl(100000);
    tcph->doff = 5;  
    tcph->fin=0;
    tcph->syn=0;
    tcph->rst=0;
    tcph->psh=0;
    tcph->ack=1;
    tcph->urg=0;
    tcph->window = htons (5840);
    tcph->check = 0; 
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

    skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

    p_usr_data = skb_put(skb, usr_data_len);    
    skb->csum = csum_and_copy_from_user(p_usr_data, usr_data, usr_data_len, 0, &err);

    tcph->check = 0;
    tcplen = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + usr_data_len;
    tcph->check = tcp_v4_check(tcplen,
                               iph->saddr, iph->daddr,
                               csum_partial((char *)tcph, tcplen, 0));

    skb->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    skb->dev = dev;
    skb->pkt_type = PACKET_HOST;
    skb->priority = 0;

    return skb;
}
```

While you can see that src/dst IPs and src MAC are hardcoded, I know how to obtain these values. However, the problem that I am experiencing is in setting dstmac to the next hop MAC towards dst IP.

You can assume that ARP table already contains the necessary information about the destination, thus I would like to avoid crafting my own ARP and then decode them myself. Moreover, this function (in my code example) is expected to be run multiple times, thus I dont want to repeat sending ARPs, but instead read the existing ARP cache somehow from the kernel.

Comment: You should use ARP protocol to retrieve the MAC address.

Comment: @LPs could you please give an example or point to the functions that I could use in the kernel for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: An ARP request is a special layer-2 frame which is broadcast on layer-2. The ARP reply will contain the layer-2 address of the layer-3 address. It is a simple matter to craft an ARP request and decode the ARP reply.

Comment: Please show your code so that we can understand what you've actually done..

Comment: I also have same issue .I think routing tables can be looked up using fib_lookup() in the kernel and related mac addr can be got using neigh_lookup ...any idea or Did you get a solution ?